# How can you specify grouped column names inside a function with kableExtra?

Tags: r, knitr, kableextra

```
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)


kable(head(mpg)) %>% kable_styling %>% add_header_above(c(" " = 6,
                                               "foobar" = 5))
```

Works well when you want to specify the grouped column header manually:

[image: enter code here]

However I want to put this feature inside a function, I've tried:

```
a_function <- function(my_column_head_name){
kable(head(mpg)) %>% kable_styling %>% add_header_above(c(" " = 6,
                                               my_column_head_name = 5))
}

a_function("foobar")
```

But this returns the named argument as the column header name:

[image]

I'm guessing this is something to do with lazy evaluation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The header is a named character vector with colspan as values. You have to create the vector and assign names with names().

```
a_function <- function(my_column_head_name){
  myHeader <- c(" " = 6, my_column_head_name = 5)
  names(myHeader) <- c(" ", my_column_head_name)
  kable(head(mpg)) %>% kable_styling %>% add_header_above(myHeader)
}

a_function("foobar")
```

Comment: The second line could be simply `myHeader <- c(6, 5)`.  I'm not sure the function would be clearer if you did that, but it would be worth mentioning in your answer.